# round corners in a image

Tags: css, image, rounded-corners

I want to display my images with rounded corners  in a web page.
i want to bring the below effect on my image in a page 
see the image

[image: Rounded Image]

Answer (score 1):

For a CSS solution try this

`<img src="yourimg.jpg" style="border:1px #000 solid;-moz-border-radius:5px;border-radius:5px;-webkit-border-radius:5px;"/>`

**Note:**
border-radius is a CSS3 tag so it will not work in old browsers

Comment: This will work in most of the CSS3 complaint browser available nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jQuery Curvy Corners plugin](http://www.curvycorners.net/) that does its job in cross-browser fashion.

Answer (score 0):

i use a pure html+css solution, guaranteed crossbrowser. An overlay.

Get a picture with your border in it. With the area where you want to show the picture transparent. Then position it on top of a normal image. Like so:

```
.overlayable         { position:relative; display:block; }
.overlayable span    { position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; }

    <a href="http://link.com" class="overlayable">
      <img src="imageToShow.png" alt="awsome picture" />
      <span>
        <img src="overlayImageWithRoundedCorners.png" alt="" />
      </span>
    </a>
```

But you can do it with a `<div>` aswell if you like.

Answer (score 0):

the jQuery plugin lc_roundz will do the job dynamically - even if you want the corners to be transparent (e.g. for use on complex backgrounds, ...).

```
$("image").lc_roundz({  
radius: 20,  // corner-radius  
newDadSelector: "", // jQuery style selector string to allow attachment anywhere in the DOM. empty string will inject the canvas next to the original  
newid: "%oid_after_lc_roundz",      // the new ID for the canvas object. %oid will be replaced with the id of the original object  
width: -1,                                                           // -1 uses the original image's width  
height: -1,                    // -1 uses the original image's width  
replace: false,                                          // boolean to decide whether the original should be removed from the DOM  
corner_color: [0,0,0,0]                     // this means TRANSPARENT ... R,G,B,alpha [0-255] each  
});
```